# How to implement OAuth2 server with CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am using CherryPy serving up information through a web service. I want to restrict access to some of the functions utilizing OAuth2. I see an example of an OAuth2 server at https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/example/server.py , however, it utilizes its own webserver. How can I integrate this with adding support to CherryPy?

Answer (score 0):

here is CherryPy example application which using it: https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/twiseless/src